# Who are the contemporary proponents of the metalinguistic view about idenity statements?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-language, identity, frege

I am looking for contemporary proponents of the following thesis:

Identity statements such as "a = b" are to be interpreted metalingustically, for example as "the names "a" and "b" are coreferential".

(as opposed to: "object a is identical to object b")

I know that Frege hold this view in the Begriffsschrift and that he argues against it in the beginning of Über Sinn und Bedeutung (On Sense and Reference). However, I'd like to know whether there are contemporary proponents who argue for a metalinguistic interpretation of identity statements.